# Missing Windows Authentication Feature

Tags: windows-8, iis, windows-authentication

There's anyway to install/enable IIS Windows Authentication when it's missing in "Turn Windows Features On or Off" menu?

I'm running an Win8 machine in a Local Workgroup.

Comment: Does your version of Windows 8 even support IIS? Some versions of Windows does not support installing IIS on them for a many reasons including Microsoft being forced to remove features by govnernments.

Comment: Yes, I have installed IIS8.

Comment: You could also try the Web Platform Installer http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I looked under "Turn Windows Features On or Off" and it seems to be there (right at the bottom):

[image]

Can you please confirm that it does not exist in the location pictured above?

Comment: In the security folder I only see the following options: Basic Authentication, IP Security, Request Filtering and URL Authorization

Comment: Me too i have the same problem ... Can only see Basic Authentication, IP Security, Request Filtering and URL Authorization :'(

Answer (score 2):

This is because the version of Windows 8 you have installed, to see this option you must have Windows 8 Pro/Enterprise Edition